# Cannot launch rails app. Ask your teammates for master key and put it in ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, secret-key

I am on rails 5.1.  I had a project i worked on for a while, and then got a new computer.  I know what my rails master key is as it is still on heroku. I cloned the app off github and cannot launch it.  I continue getting this error

`Missing encryption key to decrypt secrets with. Ask your team for your master key and put it in ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]`

When I go into `production.rb` and change

`config.read_encrypted_secrets = true`
to
`config.read_encrypted_secrets = false`

and then try running the app, i still get the same error which makes no sense at all.

So then I tried to edit the secrets file that I have. I assumed that the master key is not in there.  I went

```
`EDITOR="sublime" bin/rails secrets:edit`
```

and still get

```
`Missing encryption key to decrypt secrets with. Ask your team for your master key and put it in ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]`
```

Ultimately I just don't know what to do.  All I want to do is work on this app, and I can't even get it started.  Does anyone have any advice on where to go here? I definitely am missing something here.

Comment: The secrets file is encrypted with the key, you need the key to decrypt the secrets. The key needs to be set in the environment variable.

Comment: So I took the rails master key that I have stored in heroku and i added it in the `secrets.yml` file. (`RAILS_MASTER_KEY: 12345`), however I still am getting the same error when I try to launch my rails server. Am I on the right track? (so sorry for the confusion on my end, this has been a few headaches for me)

Comment: Goto your Heroku App Dashboard and get the value of `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` (say `12345`) and create a file on your computer `config/master.key` and in `master.key` put the value of `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` (`12345` in our case). This should fix this.